# Django query filter by number of ManyToMany objects

Tags: django, filter, count, view, many-to-many

I have two models (Event and UserProfile) in a ManyToMany relation. I want to select just those Events that have less than a certain number of Users associated with them. So events where less than 4 people have so far signed up should be selected.

In views.py I have something like this but it is not working:

```
proposed_event_list = Event.objects.all().filter(userprofile__lt=4)
```

The relevant parts of models.py look like:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date = models.DateTimeField('Event date')

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    event_commitments = models.ManyToManyField(Event, null=True, blank=True)
```

I guess I'm not correctly filtering with all Userprofiles on each event, but I don't know how to do it.

Can you help?

Comment: Please have a look into the docs or google for annontations and aggregations with the ORM, should get you started.

Comment: I have done. I am looking for more specific advice. The standard filters given seem to filter according to specific attributes of a single related model object rather than a set of them. I suppose I am looking for information which seems a little more esoteric.

Comment: Uha, looking at Yuji's advice below, I realised I hadn't looked into what you said. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Event.objects.annotate(c=Count('userprofile')).filter(c__lt=4)
```

Comment: Superb! I had to add `from django.db.models import Count` to models.py, of course, but this has worked. Yuji, you are a very strong and important citizen.